# Parse JSON Data (Nested Array) With Mantle

Tags: json

I have such a JSON data:

```
{ 
"list": [
    [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "value"
        }
    ],
    [  
        {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "value"
        },
        {
            "name": "name",
            "value": "value"
        }
    ]
]
}
```

As you see, it has nested array. I want to parse it with [Mantle](https://github.com/Mantle/Mantle). I have tried `[NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONArrayTransformerWithModelClass:]` or `[NSValueTransformer mtl_JSONDictionaryTransformerWithModelClass:]` methods, neither works.

Could you help me find the right way? Thanks in advance.